# Iterating through Multiple URL CSV Strings in Python

Tags: python, csv, url

I want to learn how to get CSV files from URLs.

While I can make the code below work by hard coding the name of the CSV string variable, I want to learn how to iterate through many CSV strings.

```
import csv
import requests

CSV_URL_1 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/births/US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv'
CSV_URL_2 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/births/US_births_2000-2014_SSA.csv'

csv_list = []

for i in range(1,3):
    concat = "CSV_URL_" + str(i)
    csv_list.append(concat)

with requests.Session() as s:
    csv_list_dict = {}
    for i in csv_list:
        download = s.get(i) #This part is the problem
        decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
        cr= csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
        my_list = list(cr)
        csv_list_dict[i]=my_list

csv_list_dict
```

In case it's not clear, I want the "i" in download = s.get(i) to become "CSV_URL_1" on the first iteration and "CSV_URL_2" on the second (I can copy the code twice and hard code these values to get the correct result), but I can't figure out how to make this iteration work. Instead, I get a missing schema error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
concat = "CSV_URL_" + str(i)
csv_list.append(concat)
```

You are putting the strings `"CSV_URL_1"` and `"CSV_URL_2"` in `csv_list`.

But the first time your code does this:

```
download = s.get(i)
```

you are clearly expecting this to mean

```
download = s.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/births/US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv')
```

but it doesn't. It means

```
download = s.get("CSV_URL_1")
```

Now you can see why you are getting a missing schema error. There is no `https://` in the URL. Your code is computing a variable *name* and then trying to use that name as if it were a *variable*.

Do this instead:

```
CSV_URL = ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/births/US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/births/US_births_2000-2014_SSA.csv']

for i in range(2):
    download = s.get(CSV_URL[i])
```

Comment: Gah. Thank you for the explanation!